# Twitter Bootstrap 3 grid system, columns collapsing unexpectedly when zooming out

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap with xs breakpoints.  Everything is working fine except when the user zooms out, then the columns that contain no data are collapsing unexpectedly.

This is 100% zoom in Google Chrome:

[image: At 100%]

This is at 90% zoom in Google Chrome:

[image: At 90%]

Code is like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="po.showPOHeaderAlertsDialog(order)" ng-disabled="order.orderHeader.messages.length === 0 || order.orderHeader.messages === null" analytics-on analytics-category="UI Events - Cart Page" analytics-event="View PO Header Menu Alerts">
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{order.orderNumber}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div>{{(order.orderHeader.totalContCost | currency) || '$0.00'}} (CNT)</div>
        <div>{{(order.orderHeader.totalNonContCost | currency) || '$0.00'}} (OFF)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{order.orderHeader.deptDesc}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{order.orderHeader.glDesc}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">{{order.orderHeader.blankNo}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="po.showPOHeaderEditDialog(order)" ng-disabled="!po.isCartEditable || po.shouldLockCart()" analytics-on analytics-category="UI Events - Cart Page" analytics-event="Edit PO Header Menu">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Strangest thing is if I zoom out furthure, to 80%, the columns go back to normal like in the 100% view. Seems to only be happening in Google Chrome (we are using the latest version 45.0.2454.85 m as of this writing). Has me and my development team stumped.  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column doesn't contain any data please put a non breaking space in it.

eg:

```html
<div class="col-xs-2">&nbsp;</div>
```

then the column will no longer collapses.

Comment: I did conditionally put a `&nbsp;` to resolve this issue, but I thought it was very strange that it worked at 100% AND also 80% zoom but not 90%.